# Why isn't auto spellcheck enabled for title/subject?

Tags: firefox, email, microsoft-outlook, spell-check

I have noticed that both Firefox/Outlook don't have auto spellcheck for the subject text box of emails. For Firefox, I am referring to Yahoo web mail.

The subject is supposed to contain texts; then why isn't any spellcheck enabled for these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft Outlook 2007 the spell checker does check the content of the subject line. It does not do this as you type, so you don't get the squiggly lines under the misspelled words. You can configure Outlook to check spelling before you send the message.

- Select *Tools > Options*
- Click the *Spelling* tab
- Put a tick in the box *Always check spelling before sending*

I expect this will work for other versions of Outlook. It did work in Outlook 2003.

Yahoo mail does not have a spell checker. Firefox will check the spelling of text typed into fields with more than one line of text (see [this page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20spell%20checker)). The subject line in a Yahoo mail form appears to be a single line of text, so Firefox doesn't check it. The body of the message is multiple lines, so Firefox does check it.

**Update (February 14, 2016)**

Firefox can spell check single line text fields. It's just not the default. To change the setting you will have to edit the configuration as follows.

- Open a new tab
- In the address bar type about:config and press Enter.
- Click the *I'll be careful, I promise* button.
- In the Search box type *layout.spellcheckdefault*
- Double click *layout.spellcheckdefault* in the list of preferences shown in the search results.
- Set the value to 2.

The possible values for *layout.spellcheckdefault* are described [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Layout.spellcheckDefault).

Comment: Very informative answer. Just out of curiosity, why is this omitted for single line of text?

Comment: The multi-line text field and the single-line text field are different types of elements on a web page. The developers chose to add spell checking to the multi-line text field only. I dug around on the Firefox developer site for a bit but I couldn't find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that sometimes Firefox does not do spell check automatically. I have to right click in a box and select check spelling.

Answer (score -1):

Check this: *[Disable spell check feature in Firefox](http://www.trixya.net/index.php/internet/disable-spell-check-feature-in-firefox)*

Comment: that link only describes how to enable/disable. The spell checker does work for content, but not for the subject text box. I was wondering, what is the mystery (if any) behind this.